# how to create a survey that has 5 multiple choices

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hey I am trying to create a survey that asks the users to create his own question and list 5 multiple choices. My first sense is that I create two datastores and one to store the user quesiton and one to to store 5 choices mapping to the question just created.  but i dont know how exactly I should do with the 5 multiple choices and how to map them with the question. anybody has an idea? Thank you a lot

Comment: you will not be creating two datastores.  you might be creating two different Kinds, or Models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to represent one to many relation in your schema. There is an analytic [guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) for that.

```
class Question(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty()

class Answer(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty()
    question = db.ReferenceProperty(Question,
                               required=True,
                               collection_name='answers')
```

This is just the gist of how your model should look like. You can access your answers for each question in the Django rendering template like this, from the query you made in GQL and found your question. If you want to specify a max number of answers for each question you have to do it manually.

```
{% for answer in question.answers %}
    {{answer.text}}
{% endfor %}
```

I definitely recommend that you go through the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are presenting the survey question in a browser, I would definitely go with one model (in one datastore as noted by Peter) having questions and answers properties. Serialize the questions and answers into two TextProperties (be sure to escape them first). From this point, everything can be done inside Javascript by splitting the text into an array, and building any type of innerHTML you want. You may want to include a third field with meta-data about whether the question is single-answer only (radio buttons or dropdown list), or multi-select (checkboxes). One GAE entity, one get_by_id, auto-memcache if you use ndb, no additional processing costs (e.g. Django template). This is fastest and cheapest, and very flexible imho. HTH. -stevep.